# Issues with reading XML file from StreamingAssets on Android

Tags: c#, android, xml, unity-game-engine, xml-serialization

I've faced with a problem that I can't read data from XML file which is in StreammingAssets folder. On Editor everything works fine but on Android Doesn't.

```
     public void Start () {
     Type[] itemTypes = { typeof(Equipment), typeof(Weapon), typeof(Consumeble), typeof(Jevelary) };
     XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (ItemContainer), itemTypes);
     TextReader textReader = new StreamReader (Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/" + "Items.xml");
     itemContainer = (ItemContainer)serializer.Deserialize (textReader);
     textReader.Close ();
 }
```

I am sure that the problem is in this line:

```
 TextReader textReader = new StreamReader (Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/" + "Items.xml");
```

I have no Idea how to resolve it. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Google for logcat. Learn how to use it. I like it in android studio because of colored texts and filtering. Then reproduce your issue while keeping an yey on your logcat. Post your exception here so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

It is `StreamingAssets` not `StreammingAssets`. Special folders like [these](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html) are case-sensitive and must be spelt correctly in order for them to work as expected. Simply correct the spelling. If possible, copy the name directly from here(`StreamingAssets`) and paste it in the Editor. Maybe this is a typo in your question?

The main problem lies here:

```
TextReader textReader = new StreamReader (Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/" + "Items.xml");
```

You **cannot** read from the `StreamingAssets` folder with `StreamReader`. You must use `WWW` to do this in Android. Not sure if this applies to iOS too.

**1**.Read the xml file from the `StreamingAssets` folder with the `WWW` class.

**2**.Create new `StringReader` instance from the string `WWW` read.

**3**.Create new `TextReader` from the `StringReader` instance.

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(readXML());
}

IEnumerator readXML()
{
    Type[] itemTypes = { typeof(Equipment), typeof(Weapon), typeof(Consumeble), typeof(Jevelary) };
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ItemContainer), itemTypes);

    WWW www = new WWW(Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/" + "Items.xml");
    yield return www;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
    {
        string result = www.text;
        TextReader textReader = new StringReader(result);

        itemContainer = (ItemContainer)serializer.Deserialize(textReader);
        textReader.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use the file:/// prefix for the path for android.

Try debugging the path you are passing to the StreamReader, and then try opening that file from a browser using the path.

You could do something like Programmer said, using the www class.

```
#if UNITY_ANDROID
   WWW www = new WWW( "file:///" + Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/Items.xml");
#elif UNITY_EDITOR
    //your previous code which worked in the editor
#endif
```